# Classic ASP Sending errors to browser does not work on IIS7 for remote connections

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I can’t get detailed error reporting for IIS7 for ASP pages on a remote browser connection.
However, when I run the page locally on the server I do see a detailed error message.

I have enabled **Send Errors To Browser** but IIS keeps sending an internal server error.

I have unchecked **show friendly HTTP error messages** on IE.

Does anyone know how to enable error messages to be sent to a remote browser?

Answer (score 28):

If "Send Errors To Browser" is not working set also this:

Error Pages -> 500 -> Edit Feature Settings -> "Detailed Errors"

Comment: You do not need to select "500" or anything other. "Edit Feature Settings" is independent of the selected status code.

Answer (score 12):

There is an ASP setting you need to change in IIS 7

Under the **IIS** heading, open the **ASP properties**, and under **Compilation**, expand the **Debugging Properties**, there you'll find:

- **Send Errors To Browser**

Set it to **True**

As you've already done, you need to disable the **show friendly HTTP error messages** in IE.

Answer (score 11):

IIS
  - Error Pages
      - Edit Feature Settings
        - Check: **Detailed errors**

IIS
  - ASP
    - Compilation
      - Debugging Properties
        - Set: **Enable Server-side Debugging = False**
        - Set: **Send Errors To Browser = True**

In my case `Server-side Debugging` was on and it was not displaying error details on remote side. It started showing error details as soon I set `Enable Server-side Debugging = False`.

Comment: `Enable Server-side Debugging = False` was the solution for me too.

Comment: this is the only one that works for me -> IIS
  - Error Pages
      - Edit Feature Settings
        - Check: Detailed errors

Answer (score 5):

By default IIS7 intercepts HTTP status codes such as 4xx and 5xx generated by applications further up the pipeline.

In web.config replace the line

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
```

with

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" errorMode="Detailed">
```

Comment: This was the solution for my case, too, after I did [both steps outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18838090/107625).

Answer (score 3):

under prompt

1. go to `%windir%\system32\inetsrv`
2. execute inetmgr
3. in the IIS MMC select "web sites" from the three on the left
4. open the menu action\properties.
5. in the home directory tab select "configuration..."
6. in the tab "debug" enable the send error to the client and flag both the checkboxes.
7. confirm all
8. restart IIS.

I had the same error and I solved following the above steps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Add following line under this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And You are done..

Comment: <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
        </defaultDocument>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>