# Save the data received in the XMLHttpRequest to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

I'm actually stuck with a problem of file download from my nodeJs server. I spent many times on other topics, without any success...

I have an app on the client that propose to download some text file. So I put this code for download process:

```
'click .downloadF': function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    var file = $target.model();

    var download = $.get('/files/download'+'?'+Math.random(),
                        {id:file.id});
  },
```

Up to here...very simple. 
On my nodeJS side I made that:

```
app.get('/files/download', function(req, res) {
var filePath = metrology.DownloadFile(req.query.id);

var filename = path.basename(filePath);
var mimetype = mime.lookup(filePath);

res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Metrology.csv");
res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

var filestream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
filestream.pipe(res);
```

});

In the Response I get the right text data and the header is correctly set to attachement and file type.
Response :

> Connection    keep-alive 
>   Content-Disposition   attachment;
>   filename=Metrology.csv 
>   Content-Type  text/csv 
>   Date  Mon, 16 Jun 2014
>   15:17:25 GMT Transfer-Encoding    chunked X-Powered-By    Express

Content:

> NoPiece;NoRepetition;Mesure;Resultat; 1;1;1;3; 1;1;2;2; 1;1;3;2;
>   1;1;4;2; 2;1;1;2; 2;1;2;2; 2;1;3;2; 2;1;4;2;

Now... how can I open a dialog window to save these data into a specified filepath ???

I'm actually debuging on Mozilla, but have to work with IE9/11 too.

Many thanks for help, ideas, suggestions and (maybe) solutions :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612009/open-save-as-dialog-box-to-download-image

Comment: Sorry but everywhere I saw the same information : need to define Content-Disposition to attachment... but in my case, I receive the data, but no dialog box is opened to save the file... Please HELP :-/

Answer (score 0):

Is the jQuery `.get` function necessary? Does `window.location.href` accomplish your goal?

```
'click .downloadF': function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    var file = $target.model();

    window.location.href='/files/download'+'?'+Math.random()+'&id='+file.id;
  },
```